# Null Pointer Exception with Multiple Classes in Processing

Tags: nullpointerexception, processing

I'm trying to make a button class for a tic tac toe game in Processing. My code for the class is this

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Button extends PApplet{

    float buttonX;
    float buttonY;
    float buttonWidth;
    float buttonHeight;
    boolean cliked;

    public Button(PApplet canvas, float buttonX, float buttonY, float buttonWidth, float buttonHeight) {
        this.buttonX = buttonX;
        this.buttonY = buttonY;
        this.buttonWidth = buttonWidth;
        this.buttonHeight = buttonHeight;
    }

    public void drawButton() {
        rect(200, 200, 200, 200);
        textSize(40);
        fill(200, 200, 200);
        text("Start Game", 300, 300);
    }

}
```

The code inside of the `setup()` method for Processing is

```
Button startButton = new Button(this, 200, 200, 200, 200);
startButton.drawButton();
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, but I keep receiving a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: An NPE question with no stacktrace and without the relevant code is unsolvable. Please at the exception message and the lines of your code pointed by the stracktrace

Comment: @Dici Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question, not a Java question. The `NullPointerException` does not have a stack trace, and is not caused by the typical Java reasons.

Comment: @KevinWorkman There is no stacktrace? How can you know where the exception is? And what is `null`? These questions are really confusing. Maybe removing the Java tag would be a good idea?

Comment: @Tunaki No, there isn't usually a stack trace. Even when there is, it refers to compiled Java code, not Processing code, so it can be very confusing or even misleading to use for debugging. Getting a NPE in Processing is not as straightforward as getting one in Java.

Comment: Hmm I had overlooked this

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because you've got two classes that extend `PApplet`. You should only have one class that extends `PApplet`. Think of that class as your sketch, and then all other classes need to refer to it to draw stuff to your sketch.

You pass a `PApplet canvas` into your `Button` constructor. Instead of having your `Button` class also extend `PApplet`, you need to use that `canvas` variable to do your drawing. It should look something like this:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Button{

    PApplet canvas;
    float buttonX;
    float buttonY;
    float buttonWidth;
    float buttonHeight;
    boolean cliked;    

    public Button(PApplet canvas, float buttonX, float buttonY, float buttonWidth, float buttonHeight) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.buttonX = buttonX;
        this.buttonY = buttonY;
        this.buttonWidth = buttonWidth;
        this.buttonHeight = buttonHeight;
    }

    public void drawButton() {
        canvas.rect(200, 200, 200, 200);
        canvas.textSize(40);
        canvas.fill(200, 200, 200);
        canvas.text("Start Game", 300, 300);
    }
}
```